# Looking for mod_rewrite regular expression feature in grep

Tags: grep, expression

Because picture (or example) is worth more than thousand words, I'll use an example:

```
RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9]+)$ /content.php?id=$1
```

In this RewriteRule example we've got simple regular expression. $1 is a reference to something that is captured by ([0-9]+), so it is reference to some number if the matching exists. Is it possible to do something like that in grep?

Let's say, some xml document contains the following :

```
<someTag>someValue</someTag>
```

I would like to extract only **someValue**, but input for **second_bash_script** for the following:

```
first_bash_script | grep "<someTag>\([[:digit::]]\)\+</someTag>" | second_bash_script
```

is **someValue**. Is it possible to extract only **someValue** using grep?

Thanks for any clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two separate questions, right?

The answer to the first one would be: use `sed`, `grep` doesn't do substitutions.

```
sed 's_^/products/\([0-9]\+\)_/content.php?id=\1_g'
```

The second thing can be done with `grep` using Perl regexp:

```
$ echo '<someTag>42</someTag>' | grep -oP '(?<=<someTag>)\d+(?=</someTag>)'
42
```

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse XML. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/223456

Comment: @jncraton Sure, but it doesn't mean one can't extract a numeric value from a single tag without attributes with regex.

Comment: You are quite right. As long as the XML document is fairly simple, this will work just fine. I just wanted to point out there are valid XML documents for which this solution will not work.

Comment: @jncraton I'm aware there are better technologies to parse XML, but I really need to do this with regex. Anyway thanks for you attention